# Validation issue with condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new with JavaScript validation and learning I am trying to validate form but I am getting issue with condition.

In my form I have one field which is name and one submit button.

What I am trying is:

If user click to to submit button and text box is empty give `alert('Please enter your First Name.')`

Then If user entered value which is not allowed by regex give `alert('Please enter only letters no special character allowed.');`

but I am getting first alert every time. Whats wrong i don't understand.

My Code:

```
jQuery('#send').click(function () {

    var reg_first_name = /^[A-Za-z ]{3,20}$/;

    var first_name = jQuery('#sa_first_name').val();

    if(first_name.length > 0){
        alert('Please enter your First Name.');
        document.getElementById("sa_first_name").focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (!reg_first_name.test(first_name)) {
        alert('Please enter only letters no special character allowed.');
        document.getElementById("sa_first_name").focus();
        return false;
    }

    return false;
});
```

Can you guide me?

Comment: var reg_first_name ="/^[A-Za-z ]{3,20}$/";
 if(first_name.length ==0){

Answer (score 2, accepted):

condition is wrong

```
if(first_name.length > 0){
```

if you want to check that first_name  must have value then your condition must be

```
if(first_name.trim().length == 0){
```

Comment: My intention is to say that his condition is wrong, and it was not the answer, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 3):

In case the user enters a name the `first_name.length > 0` will always be true.

You can check it like

```
if($.trim(first_name) == '')
```

to also avoid only spaces